# How can I check the authorization status of a user in Nextjs 12.1.6 middleware?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to redirect unauthenticated users to the login page with Nextjs middleware. What I currently have works locally, but not remotely:

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { cookies } = req
    if (!cookies['next-auth.session-token.0']) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/login', req.url))
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
}
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/account/:path*'],
}
```

I am using
version **12.1.6** of Nextjs
and version **4.10.0** of next-auth.

The `.get()` method that I found in the Next docs for getting the token from either the headers or the cookies of the request object does not exist yet in that version.

The `_middleware.ts` file is located in a subfolder of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this to redirect users. (**Next.js >= 12.1**)

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const currentUser = req.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token.0")?.value;

    if (!currentUser || (Date.now() > JSON.parse(currentUser).expiredAt)) {
        req.cookies.delete("currentUser");
        const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url));
        response.cookies.delete("currentUser");
        return response;
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That does not work in my case. When I try to access the token with .get(), I get an error: 
> This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.